# meaning of (array)function()

Tags: php, functions, array

I saw this piece of code that have part of the code I never saw before. What is the behavior of (array) in this scenario? so far I know the way of creating arrays in php never see this.

```
//

    $this->settings = array_merge( $this->settings_defaults(), (array) get_option( $this->settings_slug, $this->settings_defaults() ) );

   //
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking at type casting: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

What the code does is caste the value returned by [`get_option()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option) to an array. It is being done so that `array_merge()` works correctly and doesn't trigger warnings/errors. That much is pure PHP and is off-topic. The only reason I chose to answer rather than to post a comment is because the return value of `get_option()` will return various types of data depending on context. You can see that noted in the source:

> @param bool|mixed $pre_option Value to return instead of the option
>   value.
>
> https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/option.php#L42

That means that you have to manipulate the return data in order to be sure of the type of data that you are dealing with.